# Syntax for passing variables to Jquery.Post() method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, parameters

I am having a hard time with my comiler passing variables to my .Post method in Jquery...

```
    $(function () {
    $("#DemoGraphSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $("#DemoGraphID").serialize();
        var PopID = <% =PopID %>
        var options = [];
        var serializedForm = form.serialize();
        $.post("/PatientACO/SearchByDemographic", {PopID,form}, function (data) {
            options = $.map(data, function (item, i) {
                return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#PatientListToAdd").html(options.join(""));
        });
    });
});
```

The second parameter of the $.post() method... It keeps telling me I need a ":"... How does one set up variables and pass them to functions in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you pass to post method can be a well formed json object or a querystring param as below

```
//json

{ PopID: PopID, form: form }

//string

"PopID="+PopID+"&form="+form;
```

Comment: that works... You wouldn't happen to know how to serialize a form and send it to a action method in a controller that takes formCollection as a parameter would you?

Comment: You can have action accept a complex object which you can create in the js function and send it as a data parameter.

Comment: Actually, you just create a variable attach it to you form, create another variable and set it to the first object.serialize()... Pass that too post, viola... I am getting JSOn data back.  Now how to post it to my page.

Comment: Post the serialized object as a string and deserialize in the controller action using javascript serializer or any third party library like json.net.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send it as an object or as a query string.

Object:

```
{ PopID: PopID, form: form }
```

Query string:

```
'PopID='+PopID+'&form='+form
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

{PopID:PopID, form:form}

The compiler stopped throwing hatefull racists messages at me.
Thanks.